# Filtering Firebase by multiple fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get filter Firebase using multiple fields. This is more or less my object in Firebase:

```
{
    "id": "-id",
    "category": "History",
    "level": "High School",
    "pointAmount": 128,
    "pointBoost": 0,
    "photoURL": "link"
},
{
    "id": "-id",
    "category": "Physics",
    "level": "Primary School",
    "pointAmount": 128,
    "pointBoost": 0,
    "photoURL": "link"
}
```

What I'm doing now, is using an array of checkboxes in React to grab the `level` and `category` to filter by. This part is done. My question is, how can I filter the elements coming in from the database? This is how I'm doing it right now:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const assignmentsRef = firebase
        .database()
        .ref('Works')
        .orderByChild('available')
        .equalTo(true)
        .limitToFirst(9);
    assignmentsRef.on('value', snapshot => {
        let assignments = snapshot.val();
        let newState = [];
        for (let assignment in assignments) {
            newState.push({
                id: assignment,
                category: assignments[assignment].category,
                level: assignments[assignment].level,
                pointAmount: assignments[assignment].pointAmount,
                pointBoost: assignments[assignment].pointBoost,
                photoURL: assignments[assignment].photoURL,
                workText: assignments[assignment].workText,
            });
        }
        this.setState({
            assignments: newState
        });
    });
}
```

So as you can see, I'm already doing `orderByChild`. Also there will be multiple variables which to filter by. For example: If I select `History`, and `Physics` I will get both objects. Same if I select `History` and `Primary School`, but if I select `Physics` I should only get the second object. How can I filter it? There will be over 10 filters.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @FrankvanPuffelen. I think I have misread the question. I will remove the duplicate comment and simply add it as a normal comment because it can still be usefull as a reference.

Comment: Please take a look at [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase). It's not a duplicate (it's about WHERE queries instead of OR) but it still contains some useful information.

Comment: Thanks André. Agreed on it being a useful reference. I'm always considering adding the OR case to my answer there too, but it's already quite dense. :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do an `OR` of both conditions. There isn't any built-in support for returning items that match one of a number of conditions. You will have to fire a separate query for each condition, and then merge the results from all queries client-side. This is not as slow as you may expect, since [Firebase will pipeline the queries over a single connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).